# compile-time constants in mustache template

Tags: node.js, webpack, mustache, hogan.js

Suppose I have the following mustache template:

```
This is a {{#BIG_HOUSE}}really big{{\BIG_HOUSE}} house with {{NUM_WINDOWS}} windows.
```

and I happen to know at compile time whether `BIG_HOUSE` is truthy or not.  How do I pass this compile-time-constant-iness through to the template compiler?

Obviously in this case it's not very interesting, but in reality the template will be a lot larger and will include several such blocks.

I am currently using `mustache-loader` with `webpack`, so any solution specific to that would be great!  I also have the `UglifyJSPlugin` for webpack, so perhaps there is some way of using that here?

Answer (score 0):

The [`mustache-loader`](https://github.com/deepsweet/mustache-loader) returns a function which evaluates the template when given an object of parameters. This function can be executed using the [`apply-loader`](https://github.com/mogelbrod/apply-loader):

```
require('apply-loader?{obj: {BIG_HOUSE: false}}!mustache-loader!./template.html')
```